# Reading configuration properties in SpEL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

I have a `com.mycompany.condition` property in my application.yml or dev-tools. At the moment I'm injecting it on some services with

```
@Value("${com.mycompany.condition: false}") 
boolean condition;
```

and then using as a condition for `@Cacheable(condition = "#root.target.isCondition()")`. Is it possible to not inject the value, but using directly a SpEL to read the property? Using `@Cacheable(condition = "${com.mycompany.condition}")` gives the error

```
2022-03-03 15:17:11.681  WARN [...] 3044 --- [...] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)']
```

while using `@Cacheable(condition = "#{${com.mycompany.condition}}")` gives

```
2022-03-03 15:24:13.194  WARN [...] 19196 --- [...] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [#{${com.mycompany.condition}}] @1: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Cacheable(condition = "@environment.getProperty('com.mycompany.condition')")
```

Comment: Works, thank you. Do you know why the ${...} syntax wasn't working? It seemed so in the documentation.

Comment: Well, not all the expression annotation attributes supports property placeholder resolution. I wonder what doc are you mention? What really led you to think that property placeholder would work in this situation?